# Changing notification icon background on Lollipop

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-5.0-lollipop

I was going through the [Notifications design pattern](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html), and didn't find anything that talks about notification icon background. As you probably noticed, there is only a light grey background for custom notifications. But apps like Hangouts, or simply the USB Debugging notification has a custom color for their notification icon background.

Is there any possibility to change that grey into something else? (that specific circle's color programmatically)

[image: See picture]

Comment: may be they have special icon with green background?

Comment: Not sure if it is still important to anyone but since Android 6.1 there is a new flag "NotificationCompat.Builder.setColorized(boolean colorize)" which allows changing the "gray background" of a notification.

Answer (score 162, accepted):

#### 1) Obtain Color

```
int color = 0xff123456;
int color = getResources().getColor(R.color.my_notif_color);
int color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.my_notif_color);
```

#### 2) Set the Color to the Notification

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
...
builder.setColor(color);
Notification notif = builder.build();
```

The color is respected only on Lollipop and only affects background of *the small icon*. If a large icon is shown its contents are entirely your responsibility.

Source: [NotificationCompat.Builder#setColor(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setColor(int))

Comment: According to this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27023679/327011 the setColor will only change the color of the small icon. Beware.

Comment: 1) This only works on `LOLLIPOP`. 2) This does not affect the image provided by you in `setLargeBitmap`. It only colors background of small icon.

Comment: @AlexVPerl you can try my solution just below this comment

Comment: "setColor" is the correct answer IF YOU DO NOT SET A LARGE ICON. You will have the small icon display big with my_notif_color as background, no small badge added. tested on android 6.0

Comment: I have a problem i set the icon have green colour but when notification appear it changes to white automatically.

Comment: @HUSNAINSARWAR Icon *background* is set by `setColor`. Icon *foreground* is always white. All of it is white, that's why you use a silhouette for a notification. Not your launcher icon.

Comment: can you share correct sample code with icons and sizes for me please am trying this but no use white square icon only coming

Comment: @Harsha https://blog.clevertap.com/fixing-notification-icon-for-android-lollipop-and-above/

Comment: Any problems with Samsung devices? In my case `setColor` works on most devices except Samsung S7 with 7.0...

Comment: @Ziem Do you have a screenshot?

Comment: @EugenPechanec http://imgur.com/lEmLRsY as you can see text is colored but icon is not. It works OK on all emulators and on my 5X but not on Samsung S7 (7.0). But I managed to solve my issue. It appears Samsung can't handle 144px icons with #fffffe color. I rescaled and recolored it and it started working.

Comment: @Ziem 144px is overkill. Notification icon should be 4x24dp on a xxxhdpi device. I believe it's the color. AOSP always rewrites all colors in the icon. Looks like Samsung retains color information if the drawable is not pure white. Good catch!

Comment: @EugenPechanec it's inherited code and you are right 144px it's an overkill. Thankfully it works now ;). Thank you for your interest!

Comment: is it possible to change grayed out background color without customizing xml template for notification ?

Answer (score 10):

if you've defined color in colors.xml then in your NotificationBuilder add value as

```
.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.<YOUR_COLOR>))
```

That should solve your problem. 
It only affect to background of the icon.

Comment: I have a problem i set the icon have green colour but when notification appear it changes to white automatically.

Answer (score 3):

`getColor(int)` has been deprecated on `Resources`

We should now use one of these alternatives:

- `Resources`'s [getColor(int, Theme)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getColor(int,%20android.content.res.Resources.Theme))
- `ContextCompat`'s [getColor(Context context, int id)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html#getColor(android.content.Context,%20int))

Comment: I have a problem i set the icon have green colour but when notification appear it changes to white automatically..

Comment: If you're using a solid color the old method works just fine.

Comment: still white square icon onlycoming in 6.0 but before 5.0 appicon fine