# Android Push Notifications: Icon not displaying in notification, white square shown instead

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, icons

My app generates a notification, but the icon I set for that notification is not being displayed. Instead, I get a white square.

I have tried resizing the png of the icon (dimensions 720x720, 66x66, 44x44, 22x22). Curiously, when using smaller dimensions the white square is smaller.

I have googled this problem, as well as the correct way of generating notifications, and from what I've read my code should be correct. Sadly things are not as they should be.

My phone is a Nexus 5 with Android 5.1.1. The problem is also present on emulators, a Samsung Galaxy s4 with Android 5.0.1 and a Motorola Moto G with Android 5.0.1 (both of which I borrowed, and don't have right now)

The code for notifications follows, and two screenshots. If you require more information, please feel free to ask for it.

Thank you all.

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi") private void sendNotification(String msg, String title, String link, Bundle bundle) {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    resultIntent.putExtras(bundle);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            resultIntent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    Notification notification;
    Uri sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.notificationsound);
    notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.lg_logo)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentText(msg)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setSound(sound)
                .build();
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
}
```

[image: without opening the notification]
[image: notifications opened]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Notification bar icon turns white in Android 5 Lollipop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28387602/notification-bar-icon-turns-white-in-android-5-lollipop)

Comment: Here is a work around http://stackoverflow.com/a/39142981/1939564

Comment: did fix this issue ? still I am facing the same issue, in the top status bar still showing the white space for the notification if I add the transparent image

Comment: Yes, I fixed it by creating a transparent icon or targetting SDK version 20 or lower. If this doesn't fix it for you perhaps your similar problem has a different cause. I suggest setting target SDK version to 20 and checking if this changes anything. If it doesn't, not sure if this question can help you :(

Answer (score 214, accepted):

**Cause: For 5.0 Lollipop "Notification icons must be entirely white".**

> If we solve the white icon problem by setting target SDK to 20,  our app
> will not target Android Lollipop, which means that we cannot use
> Lollipop-specific features.

**Solution for target Sdk 21**

If you want to support Lollipop Material Icons, then make transparent icons for Lollipop and the above version. Please refer to the following:
https://design.google.com/icons/

Please look at http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html, and we'll see that the white style is how notifications are meant to be displayed in Android Lollipop.

In Lollipop, Google also suggests that we use a color that will be displayed behind the white notification icon. Refer to the link: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0-changes.html

Wherever we want to add Colors
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setColor(int)

**Implementation of Notification Builder for below and above Lollipop OS version would be:**

```
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    notification.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_transperent);
    notification.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.notification_color));
} else { 
    notification.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon);
}
```

**Note: setColor is only available in Lollipop and it only affects the background of the icon.**

**It will solve your problem completely!!**

Comment: Wow, thank you. I thought they SHOULD be entirely white, since some apps I have on my phone have color icons. Now I see the reason. Thank you!

Comment: Its bad form to set the targetSDK version to <21 just for the sake of icons. Its better to fix it the right way, as described in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27343202/changing-notification-icon-background-on-lollipop

Comment: if I added the transparent image also the status bar showing as blank but notification showing the icon correctly bcz I have added the custom layout

Comment: If icons are entirely white, they are a white square and no other possibilities exist. Google should use the provided app icons for notifications, otherwise apps can masquerade as a famous name app and get an impression. The very least they could do is make clear reference web page for those who should deliver the icons. But no. Instead we have to wade through fluff and BS and find nothing.

Comment: Does this mean app should always have two sets of icons - one for pre-lollipop and the transparent version for lollipop and higher versions ?

Comment: but in background when app is not in the stack it is showing the white icons ,what to do to get same result in any case

Comment: Problem solved adding -  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="20" /> in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: I tried everything but it's not working. it is still showing dot with a color mention in the manifest file

Comment: I am using Cordova, does any one know if there is a way to test for OS version to supply `iconA` for certain Android versions (5.1.1 or 6.0.1) and `iconB` for other versions (like 7, 8 & 9).  I have 5 test phones running Android versions (5.1.1 / 6.0.1 / 7.0 / 8.0 / 9). Phones running 5.1.1 and 6.0.1 are showing real app colored icons as the push notification icon, and the other phones (7+) are all showing an all white version of the same icon.  For OS versions that can still support colored icons, I want to use iconA and the others iconB.

Comment: how this will work on react native? sdkversion is 28.

Comment: @bossajie you can place these icons in android instead of react native with messaging service and usage.

Comment: R.color.notification_color means which color we need to give

Comment: Hey am asking you, R.color.notification_color means which color? is it white or black? can you tell please?

Comment: @user1448108 you can use any color with Material Icons.

Comment: Archived version of the icon guidelines is [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20150209195038/http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html#notification)

Answer (score 103):

If you are using Google Cloud Messaging, then this issue **will not be solved** by simply changing your icon. For example, this will not work:

```
 Notification notification  = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(text)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND|Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS|Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .build();
```

**Even if** ic_notification is transparant and white. It must be also defined in the Manifest meta data, like so:

```
  <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"

            android:resource="@drawable/ic_notification" />
```

Meta-data goes under the `application` tag, for reference.

Comment: Big thank you for the hint with the meta data inside the manifest.

Comment: how do you place "@drawable/ic_notification" ? is it one icon? many? is it PNG?

Comment: @LukePighetti it can be many if you are uploading different sized images for multiple screen resolutions. Otherwise, yes, it may be one PNG file on your drawable directory.

Comment: @RuchirBaronia so for the above example `res/drawable/ic_notification.png` of size 196x196?

Comment: thx @RuchirBaronia, upvoted for the `Meta-data` tag suggestion.

Comment: This is only applicable if you rely on the default messaging provided by Firebase. If you customize its behavior, it's up to the developer to set the correct icons using `.setSmallIcon()` or `.setLargeIcon()` builder.

Answer (score 53):

**(Android Studio 3.5)** If you're using a recent version of Android Studio, you can generate your notification images. **Right-click on your res folder** **> New > Image Asset**. You will then see *Configure Image Assets* as shown in the image below. Change *Icon Type* to *Notification Icons*. Your images must be white and transparent. This *Configure Image Assets* will enforce that rule.
[image: Configure Image Assets]
**Important:** If you want the icons to be used for cloud/push notifications, you must add the meta-data under your application tag to use the newly created notification icons.

```
  <application>
      ...
      <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
          android:resource="@drawable/ic_notification" />
```

Answer (score 46):

According to [Google's Design Guidelines](https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/icons.html):

> Notification icons must be entirely white.

Comment: Your answer is even better than the one I accepted. Wish I could accept yours too. I can't, but you have my +1 and my gratitude. Cheers!

Comment: though it works! you will not be able to update your app on google play if your previous app version was open to all versions

Comment: This is not a very good answer. What if, the stakeholders of the project required to target Android 7? I cannot just target any SDK version prior to that.

Comment: Downvoted this answer as it is wrong.The questioner says I am not able to run my app on sdk21. Answer says " dont use sdk 21"

Comment: This is really not a solution.

Comment: I can't find anything in the current design guidelines that specify that the icon must be white on a transparent background. Regardless of the poor documentation it still seems to be the case.

Comment: The relevant guidelines for the (small) notification icon are still available [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20150209195038/http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html#notification)

Comment: 404 - Page Not Found

Comment: Page not found and completely outdated. take my upvote! best answer ever!

Comment: Above link is not working "404-page not fount" error. For alternate, [please refer this link](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html#source.type=image&source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_stat_onesignal_default)

Answer (score 41):

Declare this code in Android Manifest:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" 

android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_name" />
```

Comment: Oh my! This one works perfect for FCM push notifications! Thanks

Comment: Where are you placing `ic_stat_name`? Is it one png? is it many? please help!

Comment: @Luke Pighetti 
In Android Studio 
Right Click on App>>New>>Image Assets>>IconType(Notification)

Comment: (I know it's been a while but) Could you please explain this? What is it supposed to do? Does it render the full color non-transparent icon or what?

Comment: This the proper answer for firebase cloud messaging notifications.

Comment: Did the same but the error persost, did you have another idea besides copy and paste from anywhere????

Answer (score 14):

i was facing same issue i tried lot of anwers but didn't get any solutions,finally i found the way to solve my problem.

- make notification icon with transparent background .The app's width and height must be like below sizes and paste all these in your project->app->src->main->res

---

- MDPI 24*24
- HDPI 36*36
- XHDPI 48*48
- XXHDPI 72*72

---

after the above paste this below line in your onMessageReceived method

---

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, News.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
            Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            {
                notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notify)
                                      //            .setContentTitle(title)
                            //                        .setContentText(message)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            } else
                {
                    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notify)
                       //                                .setContentTitle(title)
                        //                        .setContentText(message)
                            .setAutoCancel(true)
                            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            }
            NotificationManager notificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
```

### Don't forget to add this code in manifest file

```
<meta-data 
android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" 
android:resource="@drawable/app_icon" />
```

Answer (score 11):

We can do like below:

Create a new object of notification builder and call `setSmallIcon()` using notification builder object like in below code.

Create a method in which we will check on which OS version we are installing our app . If it is below Lolipop i.e API 21 then it will take the normal app icon with background color else it will take the transparent app icon without any background. So the devices using os version >= 21  will set the background color of icon using method `setColor()` of Notification builder class.

**Sample Code:**

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon(notificationBuilder));

private int getNotificationIcon(NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder) {

   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
             int color = 0x008000;
             notificationBuilder.setColor(color);
             return R.drawable.app_icon_lolipop_above;

    } 
    return R.drawable.app_icon_lolipop_below;
}
```

Comment: I've tested `setColor` on Kitkat (API 19) and IceCreamSandwich (API 15), in both case it ignored the color but **didn't crash**. So can I safely omit checking OS version?

Answer (score 11):

I have resolved the problem by adding below code to manifest,

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_name" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/black" />
```

where `ic_stat_name` created on Android Studio Right Click on res >> New >>Image Assets >> IconType(Notification)

And one more step I have to do on server php side with notification payload

```
$message = [
    "message" => [
        "notification" => [
            "body"  => $title , 
            "title" => $message
        ],

        "token" => $token,

    "android" => [
           "notification" => [
            "sound"  => "default",
            "icon"  => "ic_stat_name"
            ]
        ],

       "data" => [
            "title" => $title,
            "message" => $message
         ]


    ]
];
```

Note the section

```
    "android" => [
           "notification" => [
            "sound"  => "default",
            "icon"  => "ic_stat_name"
            ]
        ]
```

where icon name is `"icon"  => "ic_stat_name"` should be the same set on manifest.

Answer (score 7):

If you wan to provide lollipop support notification icon then make two type notification icon :

1. normal notification icon : for below lollipop version.
2. notification icon with transparent background : for lollipop and above version.

Now set appropriate icon to notification builder at run time base on OS version :

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_push_notification_transperent);
} else {
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_push_notification);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Finally I've got the solution for this issue.

**This issue occurs only when the app is not at all running. (neither in  the background nor in the foreground)**. When the **app runs on either foreground or background the notification icon is displayed properly**.(not the white square)

**So what we've to set is the same configuration for notification icon in Backend APIs as that of Frontend.**

In the frontend we've used **React Native** and for push notification we've used [react-native-fcm npm package](https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm).

```
FCM.on("notification", notif => {
   FCM.presentLocalNotification({
       body: notif.fcm.body,
       title: notif.fcm.title,
       big_text: notif.fcm.body,
       priority: "high",
       large_icon: "notification_icon", // notification icon
       icon: "notification_icon",
       show_in_foreground: true,
       color: '#8bc34b',
       vibrate: 300,
       lights: true,
       status: notif.status
   });
});
```

We've used [fcm-push npm package](https://github.com/nandarustam/fcm-push) using **Node.js** as a backend for push notification and set the payload structure as follows.

```
{
  to: '/topics/user', // required
  data: {
    id:212,
    message: 'test message',
    title: 'test title'
  },
  notification: {
    title: 'test title',
    body: 'test message',
    icon : 'notification_icon', // same name as mentioned in the front end
    color : '#8bc34b',
    click_action : "BROADCAST"
  }
}
```

What it basically searches for the notification_icon image stored locally in our Android system.

Comment: Your issue is VERY different from mine, though it has the same effect. Thanks for posting this answer, it'll probably help someone using the same tech stack you're using.

Comment: @IanWarburton: No need.

Answer (score 5):

Notifications are **greyscale** as explained below. They are not black-and-white, despite what others have written. You have probably seen icons with multiple shades, like network strength bars.

Prior to API 21 (Lollipop 5.0), colour icons work. You could force your application to target API 20, but that limits the features available to your application, so it is not recommended. You could test the running API level and set either a colour icon or a greyscale icon appropriately, but this is likely not worthwhile. In most cases, it is best to go with a greyscale icon.

Images have four channels, RGBA (red / green / blue / alpha). For notification icons, Android ignores the R, G, and B channels. The only channel that counts is Alpha, also known as opacity. Design your icon with an editor that gives you control over the Alpha value of your drawing colours.

**How Alpha values generate a greyscale image:**

- Alpha = 0 (transparent) — These pixels are transparent, showing the background colour.
- Alpha = 255 (opaque) — These pixels are white.
- Alpha = 1 ... 254 — These pixels are exactly what you would expect, providing the shades between transparent and white.

**Changing it up with `setColor`:**

- Call `NotificationCompat.Builder.setColor(int argb)`. From the documentation for `Notification.color`:

  > Accent color (an ARGB integer like the constants in Color) to be applied by the standard Style templates when presenting this notification. The current template design constructs a colorful header image by overlaying the icon image (stenciled in white) atop a field of this color. Alpha components are ignored.

  My testing with setColor shows that Alpha components are **not** ignored. Higher Alpha values turn a pixel white. Lower Alpha values turn a pixel to the background colour (black on my device) in the notification area, or to the specified colour in the pull-down notification.

Answer (score 5):

Requirements to fix this issue:

1. Image Format: 32-bit PNG (with alpha)
2. Image should be Transparent
3. Transparency Color Index: White (FFFFFF)

Source: http://gr1350.blogspot.com/2017/01/problem-with-setsmallicon.html

Answer (score 5):

I found a link where we can generate our own white icon,

> try this link to generate white icon of your launcher icon.

Open this [Link](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html#source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_stat_onesignal_default) and upload your ic_launcher or notification icon

Answer (score 3):

I have similar issue on android 8.0. Try to use WHITE icon resource. I have white square when i'm trying to use colored image for icon, when i replace it to white icon, it's start work.

Answer (score 3):

for  customized local notification,  in AndroidManifest.xml add following meta-data then it will work.

```
 <application
    android:name="xxxxxx"
        android:label="xxxxxx"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        
        >

       <meta-data
                android:name="your_apps_bundle_id.default_notification_icon"
                android:resource="@drawable/ic_notif" />

......
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use different icon for different versions. Simply set logic on your icon like this:

```
int icon = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP ? R.drawable.colored_: R.drawable.white_tint_icon_for_lolipop_or_upper;
```

Answer (score 1):

For SDK >= 23, please add setLargeIcon

```
notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setLargeIcon(context.getResources(), R.drawable.lg_logo))
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentText(msg)
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setSound(sound)
            .build();
```

Answer (score 1):

**When you want keep colorful icon - Workaround**

Add pixel with slightly different color into icon.
 In my case a have black icon with shades and light. When added dark blue pixel it works.

Answer (score 1):

To reduce SDK specific versions, you could simply do this: (replace '#' to '0x')

```
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
notification.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_transperent);
notification.setColor(0x169AB9); //for color: #169AB9
```

Comment: `0xFF169AB9`, you're missing the fully opaque alpha channel.

Answer (score 1):

remove the background of the icon using any of the website, suggested one is https://www.remove.bg/
and then simply use that image after downloading and your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the problem and solution after researching for 3 days!

From my experience the issue is due to tags in AndroidManifest.xml.

You should have two tags there:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/lg_logo" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

If you already have these tags, they are probably inside service tag in MainFireBaseMessagingService of AndroidManifest.xml

Copy those two meta data and place it inside application tag too.

Note that the icon supplied must be white logo with transparent background.

That way in MIUI devices such as redmi and motorola, the plain white/black box notification icon issue won't come up.