# Firebase Notification Always shows blank icon

Tags: android, firebase, android-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I'm new with **FCM**. I cannot make **FCM** use my app icon as notification icon and the icon is always a white blank one.

I imported an icon to `mipmap` folders but nothing seems changed. As some dude say that this is because of lollipop notification as [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28387602/notification-bar-icon-turns-white-in-android-5-lollipop)

But the problem is, the **FCM** notification automatically pops up and I cannot get the Notification builder to override the icon. How can I change it?

Comment: please post your code.

Comment: @Bansal what for? on Lollipop and above notification's icons are white ... asked bazillion times

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Notification bar icon turns white in Android 5 Lollipop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28387602/notification-bar-icon-turns-white-in-android-5-lollipop)

Comment: @Selvin it is not the same question, cause I do not pop notification by my self in firebase so I do not control on icon and color.

Comment: @Mateusz Pryczkowski your answer is right post it again

Comment: You always have access to notification. your app can not show notification without setting FirebaseMessagingService.check  https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive
There you can use solution from given link in your question itself

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This is the default behaviour of FCM. When app is in background it will take white icon.

Use this tag and put it in your Manifest. For me this worked. Hope it works for you too. Ensure meta-data is inside application like the example mentioned in [quickstart](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/messaging/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml#L16)

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
    <!-- [START fcm_default_icon] -->
    <!-- Set custom default icon. This is used when no icon is set for incoming notification messages. -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_ic_notification" />
    <!-- Set color used with incoming notification messages. This is used when no color is set for the incoming
         notification message. -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
    <!-- [END fcm_default_icon] -->
    <!-- [START fcm_default_channel] -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
        android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id" />
    <!-- [END fcm_default_channel] -->
    <activity
        android:name=".EntryChoiceActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".kotlin.MainActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".java.MainActivity" />
```

Comment: Its the only way that i found for how correct icon. Its a firebase bug for showing notifications in background mode. Firebase pick default app icon instead your definition on your notification builder.

Comment: should this be placed inside `application` tag or outside?

Comment: Inside the application tag

Comment: How do you place ic_app_icon in res? Is it a PNG? SVG? is there one? Is there one for each hdpi?

Answer (score 19):

If you are having this problem

[image]

See this link: [Icon not displaying in notification: white square shown instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30795431/icon-not-displaying-in-notification-white-square-shown-instead)

I had the same problem. I solved by making transparent image from designer.
Make sure your logo should be 72*72 pixels.

NOTE: Don't time waste in googling this issue, you just need a transparent icon which should be 72*72 dimensions.

Comment: "An answer" which is only link to a duplicate question is not an answer...

Comment: I gave him exact answer so he might not waste his time and focus on solving the issue.

Comment: thanks i saw the link. but where should I implement Notification builder. cause in FCB android pop notification automatically.

Comment: I up voted you because it was part of my answer. but I can not replace FCM auto generated notification icon.

Comment: actually fcm is totally different from gcm. There are two types of notifications in fcm. You have to study about it. This is the very good documentation https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Google-Cloud-Messaging . One more thing in fcm if your app is in background, notifications won't hit onMessageReceived(). For this you need to do server side coding. from server the response should be like, check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37358462/firebase-onmessagereceived-not-called-when-app-in-background , see(Ankit Adlakha) answer

Comment: also add  <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"

            android:resource="@drawable/ic_notification" /> in manifest file above application tag :)

Comment: @DäñishShärmà, you are right. Your *NOTE* helped me alot :)

Comment: Also, icon should not be SVG

Comment: That's worked, thank you. One small note, don't use [android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"] in this case.

Comment: Worked well. Clearly explain. Thak you

Answer (score 5):

The only thing that worked for me was to **generate a *Notification icon* image asset in Android studio.**
To use the an image as the notification icon, just set Asset type to "Image" and select the file.

Tip #1: use an icon which is of white color, on transparent background!

Tip #2: if the preview on the right side of the window contains only white squares, your notification icon will look just like that - white squares!
[image]

Tip #3: the Name of the asset is what should be added into the `meta-data` tag in AndroidManifest

```
<meta-data
 android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
 android:resource="@drawable/whatever_you_set_for_image_asset_name" />
```

Source: Taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57715369/2101117)

Answer (score 2):

Keep your notification small as **72 x 72** and make it **completely white**. See the photo attached with this answer.

Then paste the codes below into your manifest.

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
 android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_money" />
```

[image]

You can make a new icon from default icons pack of Android Studio.

For this right click on your **drawable folder** > **New** > **Image Asset**

Answer (score 1):

I faced same problem and did everything suggested here and nothing worked.

Eventually, **downgrading the firebase plugin from 11.8.0 to 11.6.0 resolves it** with the help of this [github issue](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/418).

This might also help someone.

Answer (score -1):

When no icons are set for incoming notifications, firebase will take the default icon and shows notification.

To override the default icon add below code into your Android manifest file

```
<meta-data
 android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
 android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_ic_notification" />
```

For more information you can follow the [link](http://%3Cmeta-data%20%20%20%20%20android:name=%22com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon%22%20%20%20%20%20android:resource=%22@drawable/ic_stat_ic_notification%22%20/%3E)