# Firebase push notification app icon is missing

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, notifications, push

I am using firebase cloud messaging for push notification in the unity android app, I am getting a small icon fine but missing the right side app icon. Please check the attached image.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whMn5.jpg) I am looking for a solution but did not find one.
If one has a solution please share. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add the code you have tried

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39828704/firebase-notification-always-shows-blank-icon

Answer (score 0):

Please share your notification code,

or try with below code **smallIcon()** method

NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(baseContext).setLargeIcon(large_icon)
.setSmallIcon(image);

Hope it will work..!!