# How to get the icon to display for push notification message

Tags: android, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

How do get my icon to show up next to a push notification message in android. I have a cordova app and I see the icon for iOS push message but on Android there is a  a white circle next to my push message .

I have this setup in my config.xml file

```
<platform name="android">

        <icon src="splash/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="splash/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="splash/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="splash/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="splash/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="splash/icon/android/icon-144-xxhdpi.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="splash/icon/android/icon-192-xxxhdpi.png" />

    </platform>
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Hello you just call this method from onMessageReceived() in
>   MyFirebaseMessagingService you can get a notification icon instead of
>   white icon. Hope this might be helps you. This is for android. like this :- [Icon not displaying in notification: white square shown instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30795431/icon-not-displaying-in-notification-white-square-shown-instead)

```
private void sendNotification(String message, String mAction) {
        int id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = null;
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | 
        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        } else {
            notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        }
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(id, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
```

Comment: Please do not copy answers from other question. The correct response is to flag this question as a duplicate.