# No Icon/Empty white icon in received remote notification

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native

I'm receiving remote notifications successfully on Android, showing Title, message, and body.

But the icon used for the notification is always an empty white icon !

This is a sample of the notification schema:

What am I missing ?

```
{
    "data": {
        "Notification": "{\"Name\":\"Extra json to be parsed by react when clicking the notification\"}",
        "title": "You have a new message from X",
        "message": "You have a new message from X",
        "body": "You have a new message from X"
    }
}
```

I've used below package

```
"native-base": "^0.5.2",
"react": "16.0.0-alpha.3",
"react-native": "0.43.1",
"react-native-notifications": "^1.1.10",
"react-native-router-flux": "3.38.0",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^4.0.0"
```

[image]

index.android.js

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    this.handleConnectionChange;
    NotificationsAndroid.setNotificationOpenedListener((notification) => Actions.forums());
    NotificationsAndroid.setRegistrationTokenUpdateListener((deviceToken) => global.deviceID = deviceToken);
    NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener('change', this.handleConnectionChange);
}
```

Comment: post your current code !

Comment: update the pushnotification recivedcode

Comment: I don't know about react but in native development if ur project target sdk version >= lollipop, the notification icons will be black and white.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30795471/4070044

Comment: @rushankshah please check my sample code here: https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/issues/489 I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Has you put icon parameter in your notification payload?.. you may refer FCM doc - https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.messaging.NotificationMessagePayload#icon