# Notification icon is not showing in all android version in background

Tags: android, android-notifications

i am working on push notification in which my app icon is showing correctly in foreground in all android versions,**But the problem is that when my app goes in  Background the notification icon is showing total white in all android version weather its lollipo or greater.**,I have used transparent icon also and tried lot of solutions but didn't work anyone i dont know why?

Thank you in advance

> Dimensions

**MDPI**:-24*24

**HDPI**:-36*36

**XHDPI**:-48*48

**XXHDPI**:-72*72

> MyFirebaseMessagingService.class

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    {
        notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_logo)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    } else
    {
        notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_logo)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    }
```

> Notification panel
> [image]

Comment: What is the difference between the code of If and Else block? These two are exactly same. @Sunil

Comment: @Ankita yes i know this is wrong ,so how can i solve my problem?

Comment: Follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30795431/icon-not-displaying-in-notification-white-square-shown-instead