# How to view notification icon What i put it programmatically not app icon android marshmallow

Tags: android, notifications

How to view notification icon What i put it programmatically not view app icon  android >= marshmallow, in android 5 and 4.. icon appear normally but in android 6 ,7 it appear app icon any one know the problem?

Comment: you should put some code here?

Comment: did you use `setSmallIcon` and `setLargeIcon`?

Comment: You should create `drawable-v21` folder and put your notification icon in this folder. If it doesn't resolve your problem. You can visit this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28387602/notification-bar-icon-turns-white-in-android-5-lollipop or this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30795431/icon-not-displaying-in-notification-white-square-shown-instead

Comment: I use :Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
.setContentTitle("Hello")
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.clock)
.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MIN)
.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
.setOngoing(true).build();