# Icon is not displaying in push notifications in ionic 2

Tags: android, ionic-framework, push-notification, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I am trying to display app icon in notification. But it is displaying blank icon.

I have given pushoptions as below:

```
 const options: PushOptions = {
      android: {
        titleKey: 'App',
        sound: 'true',
        icon: 'res/drawable/notification_icon',
        topics: ['MyTopic']
      },
      ios: {
        alert: 'true',
        badge: false,
        sound: 'true'
      },
      windows: {}
    };
```

and copied the icon image as below which has resolution of 40*40px.

```
<resource-file src="resources/notification_icon.png" target="res/drawable/notification_icon.png" />
```

Is there anything that I am missing?
[image]

Update:

I followed this link : https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/608 and tried it by copying all the notification icon under resources/android/notification/drawable-XYZ/ic_stat_ac_unit.png to res/drawable-XYZ/ic_stat_ac_unit.png using the following statements:

```
<resource-file src="resources/android/notification/drawable-hdpi/ic_stat_ac_unit.png" target="res/drawable-hdpi/ic_stat_ac_unit.png" />
        <resource-file src="resources/android/notification/drawable-mdpi/ic_stat_ac_unit.png" target="res/drawable-mdpi/ic_stat_ac_unit.png" />
        <resource-file src="resources/android/notification/drawable-xhdpi/ic_stat_ac_unit.png" target="res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_stat_ac_unit.png" />
        <resource-file src="resources/android/notification/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_stat_ac_unit.png" target="res/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_stat_ac_unit.png" />
        <resource-file src="resources/android/notification/drawable-xxxhdpi/ic_stat_ac_unit.png" target="res/drawable-xxxhdpi/ic_stat_ac_unit.png" />
```

and modified PushOptions in app.component.ts to :

```
android: {
    titleKey: 'App',
    sound: true,
    vibrate:true,
    icon: 'ic_stat_ac_unit',
    iconColor:'#343434',
    topics: ['MyTopic']
  }
```

Even this did not worked - Same Issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the ionic fcm plugin to fix the issue. I just replaced cordova push plugin with Cordova fcm plugin icon displayed. I wasted a lot of time on push plugin.I hope this answer helps others.

Please refer to below links for more information :

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/fcm/

https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm

Answer (score 2):

it is probably of not setting the alpha channel on the icon in the shape you want to display. Android 5.0+ adds a white mask to all small notification icons. you can be using the [Android Asset Studio](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html#source.type=clipart&source.clipart=ac_unit&source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_stat_onesignal_default) to create the icon set as it will show you how it will look on the device to make sure you have it correct.

> In Android 5.0+, push notification icon has to be two-color:
>   transparent background + white foreground; otherwise the default app
>   icon is taken, and anything non-transparent is displayed as white (so
>   very likely, the user will see a white)

Comment: I tried with https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vr27p.png which is showing on Android Asset Studio link but not on device. FYI, I am using ionic 2

Comment: @user1188867 for Ionic , please gothrough this [issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/608​) it should guide you the correct path

Comment: I think url link is broken. Please verify and post it again.

Comment: @user1188867 actually opeing from comment its not working , try this out https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/608

Comment: I have looked at it and tried it before but it did not work for me. I will try it again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156893/discussion-between-webruster-and-user1188867).

Answer (score 1):

I think you get your answer from below link:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30795471/7329597

I hope it helps you.:)