# Notification icon app background android

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

I'm stuck on setting notification icon for my app. In my code I have both this:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                    R.drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)).....
```

and this:

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_ic_notification" />
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
```

So, when the app is open works correctly, I see the drawable image.
But, when the app is in background or closed, I see a blank image. I suppose that this blank image is the gray version of my app icon.

Is it correctly? How can I set any image for the notification in case of the app is in background?

EDIT

How the notification appears:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkdRt.jpg

Comment: Have a look at their documentation. It might help you.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

Comment: @ruch ehm..I read all on Google Firebase website...and I'm here because I didn't find enough information

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Icon not displaying in notification: white square shown instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30795431/icon-not-displaying-in-notification-white-square-shown-instead)

Comment: @lucacatr: Please take in mind that everyone is trying to help you. You may have read the docs, but you haven't specifically mentioned that. Many new people post on SO when they need help, but there are many instances where they haven't attended to the doc itself. That's why I did. Adding more, your tone doesn't seem to be the best in a forum like SO.

Comment: @Ruchira: I agree that it's important for readers to be able to understand what steps have been taken to solve a problem. However, we don't want to encourage question authors merely to say "I have read the docs" or "I have tried lots of things" since those assurances in themselves are not specific or useful, and they become a standard boilerplate that might be added by people who in reality have not read any docs at all.

Comment: Regarding "tone", it's worth considering that most people are amenable in real life, and a friendly/earnest tone just does not carry well in short comments. It is probably just best not to mention that sort of thing, and instead flag a comment if you think it violates [the 'be nice' policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice).

Comment: Hi @halfer. Thank you for your advice. I agree with you on that certain short comments might not reflect well as it would have in the real world.
I wasn't aware of the "be nice policy" before. I'll definitely flag from now onwards. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_logo)
            .setContentTitle(title.toString())
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setContentText(sp.toString());
```

Try using this, icon_logo is the icon image in the drawable.

Comment: it's working fine on my application, share some more code or if it's on github u can share that

Comment: Working also on Android 6 and also if the app is in background?

Comment: yes it's working can u share the code so that i can check!

Comment: i just showed you the code this is the only thing used to create notification, atleast show the image how the notification is coming

Comment: I shared an example of notification

Comment: just write the code I have written above and put the image of logo u want in the drawable folder, I have just again checked on my app it's working fine

Comment: Do you set "targetSdkVersion 20" in gradle?

Comment: my targetsdk is 25