# Android Notification small icon not showing white square instead in 7.1.1 above

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

In push notification, the small icon is not showing in 7.1.1 above OS.White square like coming

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
Notification notification = mBuilder.
        setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon).
        setTicker("testing").setWhen(0)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
        .setContentText(message)
        .build();

notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

I'm using transparent background but I'm not able to show correctly please help me.Even I follow the android icon design guidelines.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Icon not displaying in notification: white square shown instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30795431/icon-not-displaying-in-notification-white-square-shown-instead)

Comment: @Sree I checked that one but below 7.1.1 OS it's working

Comment: can you be try `.setColorFilter(Color.WHITE)`

Comment: @Sree I tried with color also, still i face the problem

Comment: have you found any solution on this ??