# Why doesn't Android notifications show icon I set?

Tags: android, notifications

I am following the Google Android develop fundamental tutorials for Android practice.When it comes to notifications, there isn't icon I set showing on the left of the notification.
The tutorials are [here](https://google-developer-training.gitbooks.io/android-developer-fundamentals-course-practicals/content/en/Unit%203/82_p_alarm_manager.html).

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ToggleButton mToggleButton;
private NotificationManager notificationManager;
private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID=0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    notificationManager=(NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mToggleButton= findViewById(R.id.alarmToggle);
    //改变togglebutton文字
  //mToggleButton.setTextOff("Off");
//  mToggleButton.setTextOn("On");
//  mToggleButton.setText("Off");
    mToggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new 
CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            String toastMessage;
            if (b){
                toastMessage=getString(R.string.toggleButton_on);
                deliverNotification(MainActivity.this);
            }
            else {
                toastMessage=getString(R.string.toggleButton_off);
                notificationManager.cancelAll();
            }
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,toastMessage,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

public void deliverNotification(Context context){

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent =PendingIntent.getActivity(
            context,NOTIFICATION_ID,notificationIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

//    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context,"StandUp")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_run)
            //这里设定的图标是AS里随便找的一个，设置了没效果
            //this doesn't work.ic_run comes from AS notifications image asset.
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.notification_title))
            .setContentText(getString(R.string.notification_text))
            .setContentIntent(notificationPendingIntent)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setAutoCancel(true);

//        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID,builder.build());
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID,builder.build());
    }
}
```

Here is the outcome:on the left side of the notification is the default android launcher

[image]

**Update** :
This time I follow this [lesson](https://google-developer-training.gitbooks.io/android-developer-fundamentals-course-practicals/content/en/Unit%203/81_p_notifications.html). I changed the setting of notification to below:

```
        mNotifyManager=(NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("Battery Alert!")
            .setContentText("Your battery is out of use.")
            .setContentIntent(notificationPendingIntent)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_stat_name,"Learn More",learnMorePendingIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_update,"Update",updatePendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setDeleteIntent(dismissPendingIntent);//设置划掉通知产生的广播
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
        notifyBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_battery);
        notifyBuilder.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
    }
    else{
        notifyBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_battery);
    }
```

This doesn't work.
[image: Only the text color of action button changed to the color I set]

Icon:
[image: ic_battery] `ic_battery`
What am I missing?

Comment: `target api:26` Device `Meizu Note6`OS:`Flyme OS`

Answer (score 0):

You should set notification icon based on API version.

```
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    notification.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_transperent);
    notification.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.notification_color));
} else { 
    notification.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon);
}
```

Refer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30795471/2147481

Comment: Hi sir, I followed your advice but it didn't work. This time I followed this [lesson](https://google-developer-training.gitbooks.io/android-developer-fundamentals-course-practicals/content/en/Unit%203/81_p_notifications.html), I change the   notification setting to the updated question.