# Oreo Notification Icon not displaying

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notifications

I have Used targetSdkVersion 26 & Notification Icon is not displaying . When I changed to targetSdkVersion 20 it's working correctly. But when I am uploading the app to play store it's not downgrading. How can I show icon in targetSdkVersion 26. [Notification small icon 72X72](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYhjG.png),
[Notification home screen icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7yd5.png)

Comment: for that you have to create new white transparent icon logo of your app and you have to compare version and add icon as small icon at run time

Comment: What is the resolution of the icon and show me some code snippet

Comment: you can refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/30795471/7348352

Comment: Ya according to answer only I followed but after 8.0 comparing also it is not showing. Below is my code

Comment: if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            b.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.cp_logo);
            b.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
        } else {
            b.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.cp_logo);
        }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here i use the size of icon

```
mipmap-mdpi : 24*24
mipmap-hdpi : 36*36
mipmap-xhdpi : 48*48
mipmap-xxhdpi : 72*72
```

and I have store it into mipmap named as `logo_white.png`  so while building a notification you can use this like

```
 notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon())...


notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "default")
                .setSmallIcon(icon)
                .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(data.get("message")))
                .setContentText(data.get("message"))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorPrimary))
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);
```

Here is the method

```
private int getNotificationIcon() {
    boolean useWhiteIcon = (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP);
    return useWhiteIcon ? R.mipmap.logo_white : R.mipmap.app_icon;
}
```

Here `app_icon` is normal app icon and `logo_white`  is white transparent app icon

Comment: I have edited logo check in question  added logo in question,still it's not showing

Comment: I have added a new code in answer as I  use while building a notification ,check and try again and let me know if you get any issues

Comment: image icon you have created is not Proper ... the text CP should be transparent

Comment: How to create a transparent icon is there any tool to create.

Comment: But is working fine for targetSdkVersion 20 when i change 26 the problem i am faceing.

Comment: after marshmallow there is a change in notification icon pattern as you can see if image icon is not vector then it will display the color you have provided at a time of notification builder so if you create an vector icon in which the text CP  should be transparent so it will get that color and fill your CP text and rest of the area is cover by the image so it will look like your app logo

Comment: Yes Its Coming,Thanks Jay. The probelm the transparent image.

Answer (score 3):

easy way to set notification you should right click on drawable or your mipmap folder  and choose image asset and set icon type notification Icon and choose your transparent image notification.

Thanks.