# My notification, App Setting icon, and apk icon still use default icon

Tags: android

I already doing anything on tutorials on stack overflow.

add icon and logo on a manifest, uninstall an old app, rename image asset, restart the phone, but it does not work.

Its default logo is displaying on APK, App setting, and Notification. But New Logo displaying only on the home launcher.

I want all icon to get change with a new icon.

This error looks like this:

[image: Its look like this]

**EDIT**

This is my code for notification:

```
var mBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.app_icon)
            .setContentTitle("My notification")
            .setContentText("Hello World!")
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)

        var mNotificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager;

        mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build())
```

My phone is **Xiaomi 4A**, Android **Marshmallow**.
I use Kotlin for my code.

My point is, I tried to change my apps icon. My apps icon was changing on a home launcher. but on APK Icon, Apps Setting Icon, and notification Icon was not changing and still using default green with Android head Icon. Why some icon still use default icon? what's wrong with me??

Comment: Please post the code snippet of where the notification is being created, since the drawable resource would be passed there. Have you checked if that one is matching your new logo's resource ID?

Comment: @TheGamer007 Okay, wait a minute

Comment: `R.mipmap.app_icon` is your updated logo? And you're still seeing this default one in the notifs? Could you try having a logo file in the drawables folder, and then passing that instead? For ex: `R.drawable.app_icon`

Comment: @TheGamer007 I add my source on EDIT

Comment: @TheGamer007 Yes, it is matched with my new logo

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30795431/android-push-notifications-icon-not-displaying-in-notification-white-square-sh

Comment: @ADM No, it's different, not only notification. My APK Icon and icon on app setting too

Comment: @ADM And I don't Run it in Oreo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use MIUI, disable MIUI optimization in developer settings.

Answer (score 0):

As documentations says , the notification icon size should be 48*48 .
i have faced this issue before and i solve it with this code 
`private int getNotificationIcon() {
     boolean whiteIcon = (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP);
            return whiteIcon ? R.drawable.ic_launcher_2:R.mipmap.ic_launcher;
        }`

Comment: What's your Android version ?

Comment: My android is Marshmallow

Comment: And my phone is Xiaomi 4A

Comment: Is your icon white with transparent background ?