# notification status bar icon doesn't change to white

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

As the title say when i launch i notify the small icon on the status bar doesnt change color to white and is almost invisible:

[image]

[image]

```
Notification n  = new Notification.Builder(this)
        .setContentTitle("title")
        .setContentText("lorem ipsum dolor sit amet")
        .setSmallIcon((R.drawable.logo_ntf))
        .setLargeIcon(icon)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        //.addAction(R.drawable.transparent, null, null)
        .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

After ensuring transparency of your drawable file....

Try adding the following to the Notification.Builder pipeline:

```
.setColor(color);
```

**color** should be a resource int value, referring to a colour, like so:

```
int color = getResources().getColor(R.color.notification_color);
```

The non-deprecated way:

```
int color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.notification_color);
```

Source: [setColor documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setColor(int))

Comment: Please ensure to post all necessary code.

Please post the code of R.drawable.logo_ntf as an update to your question.

Comment: with other icons of any color it works.. its really strange

Comment: OK it works. I just convert the image to black and white incrasing the sharpening. The problem could appear because the image contains gradients or is composed by many colors.

Comment: Glad to hear it.

Comment: @GiorgioCafiso If this has helped fixed the issue, please feel free to set the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For Android 5+, you have to create a transparent icon for notification small icon.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    notification.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_transperent);
    notification.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.notification_color));
} else { 
    notification.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon);
}
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30795471/4224024) for more