# notification icon dones't show in flutter andriod app local_notification_flutter

Tags: flutter, notifications

I'm new in flutter so please don't kill me if my question is easy.

notification icon doesn't show like this

[image]

I put in this path

> \android\app\src\main\res\drawable

here is my code for icon:

```
 final settingsAndroid = AndroidInitializationSettings('app_icon');
 final settingsIOS = IOSInitializationSettings(onDidReceiveLocalNotification: (id, title, body, payload) => onSelectNotification(payload));
 final settingsIOSgeneral = IOSInitializationSettings(onDidReceiveLocalNotification: (id, title, body, payload) => onSelectNotificationgeneral(payload));
 notifications.initialize(InitializationSettings(settingsAndroid, settingsIOS), onSelectNotification: onSelectNotification);
```

**Can Any one help me please how can I preview my icon in notification ?**

Comment: Looks like a proguard issue,
see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/61303224/8912043

Answer (score 17):

I did the following and it worked for me:

1. Create a transparent and white notification icon (you can use the following tool: AndroidAssetStudio )

Download the zip folder, unzip and you'll see it contains a res folder with different drawable folders. Copy and paste the contents of the res folder in "android\app\src\main\res" path

[image: Folder Structure]

2. Then open the AndroidManifest.xml file and add the following lines to it:

ic_stat_calendar_today is the name of my notification icon. And each of the drawable folders that have been pasted contain a different size of icon with the same name.

[image: Android Manifest]

3. If you want to change the color of the icon then check the above image. Add the metadata tag after the notification icon tag
4. Go to "android\app\src\main\res\values" and add a colors.xml file

[image: colors.xml]

```
<color name="colorAccent">#00FF00</color>
```

I have shared this answer in the following Github chain as well- [Solution](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17941#issuecomment-622268132).

Answer (score 5):

This could be because the icon image is not transparent -- Try the notification icon generated from [this tool](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html). Also check this question [Android Push Notifications: Icon not displaying in notification, white square shown instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30795431/android-push-notifications-icon-not-displaying-in-notification-white-square-sh)

Answer (score 1):

generate a transparent icon and then set the color in `AndroidNotificationDetails` parameter

Answer (score 1):

Icon should be transparent or BG is white
use this website to remove if you want https://www.remove.bg/upload

then open you project in Android studio, you can easily create them with the built-in tool in Android Studio. Right-click on Res folder -> New -> Image Asset -> Notification Icon (select from dropdown) there you can select any svg or image from the gallery.

then change  final

```
AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
        AndroidInitializationSettings('ic_notification');
```

ic_notification name is my image it is there in drawable folder
[image]

it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You must do three things;

1.follow @user2549980's answer and do samethins step by step but in colors.xml file, you must write encoding="utf-8" with uppercase format, like;

(your notification icon must be copied mipmap folders with same sizes, and you must add that icon name to your AndroidManifest.xml, and it must be transparent icon.)

2.Step; in your local notification init function,

```
 _notificationPlugin=FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

await _notificationPlugin.initialize(
    const InitializationSettings(
        android: AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/notification_icon'),
        iOS: IOSInitializationSettings()
    ),
  onSelectNotification: (payload) async{

  
  },
);
```

you must change this line @mipmap/icon_name with your icon name.

and I am writing this comment because, this step can be missed easily so, don't forget this step.

Answer (score 0):

(1) You don't have to put them in drawable, you can put them in mipmap (android/src/main/res/mip-map-**dpi folders) if you want.
(2) If you need to test the result, hotreload won't take effect, you have to rebuild to test the result.