# Flutter local notification icon not showing

Tags: flutter, notifications

I have an application using [Package Flutter Local Notification](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) for showing notifications. Everything is fine, I can show the notification. The problem is my image as icon notification does not show, only full color of my image.

What I have done:

- Setting InitLocalNotification like documentation

  ```
  void initLocalNotification() async {
      _androidInitializationSettings = AndroidInitializationSettings('app_icon');
      _iosInitializationSettings = IOSInitializationSettings(
        onDidReceiveLocalNotification: _onDidReceiveLocalNotification,
      );

      _initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
        _androidInitializationSettings,
        _iosInitializationSettings,
      );

      await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
        _initializationSettings,
        onSelectNotification: _onSelectNotification,
      );
    }
  ```
- Set structure folder like documentation

  [image]
- Resize my logo like logo in documentation (Width : 36px , Height : 36px , Background : Transparant, Extension : .png)

  [image]

Even though I have done the above method, my image icon is not showing, only the color.

#### Result (does not work)

[image]

After that, I tried to change my image with image from documentation, and that is working. Image icon is shown in notification.

#### Image from documentation

[image]

#### Result (works)

[image]

Did I missed something?

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the way you generate the icon. Since do you have android studio? Try Image Asset!

Comment: @Moqbel before i try to resize the image in online site, i already using this for created icon image https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio#access. But icon notification still only show color not the image

Comment: plz share your AndroidManifest.xml and also the folder structure of where the image is saved. 

You can also refer to this solution - https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17941#issuecomment-622268132

Comment: Please check this link in detail: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications#custom-notification-icons-and-sounds

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67455360/15236786

Comment: Have you tried checking this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45318614/why-is-my-smallicon-for-notifications-always-greyed-out/45318726#45318726)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [notification icon dones't show in flutter andriod app local\_notification\_flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57362439/notification-icon-donest-show-in-flutter-andriod-app-local-notification-flutter)

Answer (score 4):

If your icon displays as rectangle on release build and you are sure that your icon matches notification icon guidelines then you should try to disable shrinking resources in `build.gradle`:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        shrinkResources false
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is my signingConfig signingConfigs.debug? and changing it to release gave me  an error

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking at this.
The problem here comes from the shape of the icon.
In most android version the notification icon is just a shape filled with a color (such as the F of flutter). A rectangular icon with no transparency will be a rectangle filled with a color.

Some constructor, such as Samsung, show the actual image in some of their software version.