# Flutter local notifications Icon not showing

Tags: flutter, notifications, android-notifications

I am facing a problem that is very common, but no solution I saw helped me. So, I'm trying to show local notifications.

Everything works except the icon. Following the package's documentation, I added an icon to the drawable, but it doesn't work.

Here is the structure of my folder and the image I want to show

[image: folder structure]

Here is my code to initialization

[image: initialization code]

I tried many things. I created icons with transparency (using https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/) and added to the drawable, added the PNG as in the first image.

It only works when I copy the standard icon to the drawable, which is the Flutter logo.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [notification icon dones't show in flutter andriod app local\_notification\_flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57362439/notification-icon-donest-show-in-flutter-andriod-app-local-notification-flutter)

Answer (score 4):

### There a few thing I had to know to solve this:

#### Initialization

[flutter_local_notification](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) needs to be "initialized". Here's a function I use to initialize in my `main` function:

```
void main() async {
  // Need to "ensureInitialized" before initializing `flutter_local_notifications`
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MyApp(await initializeFlutterLocalNotifications()));
}

Future<FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>
    initializeFlutterLocalNotifications() async {
  final flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
// initialise the plugin. app_icon needs to be a added as a drawable resource to the Android head project
  // 'mipmap/ic_launcher' taken from https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications/issues/32#issuecomment-389542800
  const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
      AndroidInitializationSettings('mipmap/ic_launcher');
  final IOSInitializationSettings initializationSettingsIOS =
      IOSInitializationSettings();
  final MacOSInitializationSettings initializationSettingsMacOS =
      MacOSInitializationSettings();
  final InitializationSettings initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
      android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
      iOS: initializationSettingsIOS,
      macOS: initializationSettingsMacOS);
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);
  return flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;
}
```

### Default Icon path:

For `AndroidInitializationSettings`'s **defaultIcon** parameter, use **mipmap/ic_launcher**. Not app_icon, ic_launcher.png, etc. I discovered this from [Github: Icon not working on Android](https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications/issues/32#issuecomment-389542800)

```
const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
      AndroidInitializationSettings('mipmap/ic_launcher');
```

Answer (score 2):

Documentation of this package is not so clear about it. You need to change name `app_icon` to the icon file from your `res/drawable` folder to have an effect of your custom icon. In your case one example can be `ic_launcher.png`. Specific line in your code for a change is:

```
const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
    AndroidInitializationSettings('app_icon');
```

**Note:** If your notification icon gets grey then follow this link for solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63746521/15236786