# Flutter Android Notification Icon (Grey Square)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, notification-icons

I'm using [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) and everything is ok on debug mode but when I checked it on my phone with release mode the icon is turning grey square.

I'm also using this tool to generate monochrome white icon using just clipart: [AndroidAssetStudio](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html#source.type=clipart&source.clipart=ac_unit&source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_stat_ac_unit)

Physical Device: Samsung galaxy s10plus

- It works fine on emulator because it is debug mode?
- If I use launcher icon which is colored it works on my phone + release mode BUT grey square work on emulator. I've read that since lollipop notification icon should be monochrome.

Thanks!

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/78242398/14655727

Answer (score 17):

For others who might encounter the same issue.

You have to create /android/app/src/main/res/raw/keep.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:keep="@drawable/*" />
```

Comment: I'm running into this problem too,  Any chance you could clarify your solution a bit? Is there anything else I need to do besides this? Do I need to create the raw directory? What is causing the problem?

Comment: It works, I suspect that the icon is missing during release compilation. But it is just a guess

Comment: This does not seem to work

Comment: Didn't work for me

Comment: Yes It is not working on release build.

Comment: Thanks this worked. i think the issue was the assets were being minified

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes#toolskeep Here is the explanation of their answer.

Comment: Yes, this did it. And thank you @ZekeWillams for pointing us into the docs. For @barbecu, it is just creating the directory named `raw` and inside it the file keep.xml with the snippet shared in the answer. Take a look at the docs if you or other guys have more doubts.

Comment: you need to fix it for other sizes too 
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:keep="@drawable/mipmap-hdpi/*" />
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:keep="@drawable/mipmap-mdpi/*" />
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:keep="@drawable/mipmap-xhdpi/*" />
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:keep="@drawable/mipmap-xxhdpi/*" />
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:keep="@drawable/mipmap-xxxhdpi/*" />

Answer (score 5):

I did the following and it worked for me:

1. Create a transparent and white notification icon (you can use the following tool: [AndroidAssetStudio]https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html#source.type=image&source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=app_icon )
   Download the zip folder, unzip and you'll see it contains a res folder with different drawable folders. Copy and paste the contents of the res folder in "android\app\src\main\res" path
2. Then open the AndroidManifest.xml file and add the following lines to it:
   ic_stat_calendar_today is the name of my notification icon. And each of the drawable folders that have been pasted contain a different size of icon with the same name.
3. If you want to change the color of the icon then check the above image. Add the metadata tag after the notification icon tag
4. Go to "android\app\src\main\res\values" and add a colors.xml file

```sh
<!-- Set custom default icon. This is used when no icon is set for incoming notification messages. -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/app_icon" />
        <!-- Set color used with incoming notification messages. This is used when no color is set for the incoming notification message.  -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
```

colors.xml

```sh
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!--    color red for android notification-->
    <color name="colorAccent">#BB2030</color>
</resources>
```

+++ AND if you use .show, you can add color in function:

```sh
_flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        notification.hashCode,
        notification.title,
        notification.body,
        NotificationDetails(
          android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
            _channel.id,
            _channel.name,
            channelDescription: _channel.description,
            icon: 'app_icon',
            importance: Importance.max,
            priority: Priority.max,
            color: Color(0xFFBB2030),
          ),
        ),
        payload: jsonEncode(message.data),
      );
```

+++ References: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17941#issuecomment-622268132