# Firebase Notification icon is gray

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Although I did this solution which is in stackoverflow, the icon still the same.

```
    <meta-data   android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
android:resource="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
```

here top icon:

[image]

and when I slide top bar, I see this:
[image]

Where is the problem?
I also use this website for creating transparent icon: https://jgilfelt.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html#source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_stat_ic_launcher

Also my res file like this right now (drawable folders from above link):

[image]

icon here:
[image]

Comment: Have you added a custom icon?

Comment: In my case I put an image on the drawable like this: `<meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" android:resource="@drawable/logo" />`

Comment: What is the final icon image that you are using? Is it colored?

Comment: @bharats yes it is colored

Comment: @Diwyansh what is that

Comment: @RyanYang it does not work..

Comment: You need to add a image with no background and colored for ground such as Icon PNG file.

Comment: @Diwyansh I have icon and its background color white you can see in above. What should I do ? I think white section of the icon should remove right? I mean the text (Iyte Cepte) only the chance right?

Comment: try this kind of icon https://i.pinimg.com/originals/6e/2c/f9/6e2cf920c73d260231a7cb8a16933486.png

Comment: @Diwyansh what is the differences between this icon and mine

Comment: Refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54056662/firebase-notification-is-grey-flutter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The icon to be used for notifications must be white-colored and with transparent background else it will show a grey-colored box.

You can check out this [article](https://medium.com/nonstopio/change-the-firebase-notification-icon-in-a-flutter-245b7f7dc546) to know more.

I had the same problem and resolved it by making changes to the icon image.

Here's a sample image:
[image: Notification Logo]

Comment: I added icon img to above. Can you look and give a feedback is there any problem?

Comment: Yeah, it should be white in color and transparent

Comment: What do you mean when you say white color? It has already white background color

Comment: I have added a sample in the answer

Comment: how can i do this? Can you suggest a website etc

Comment: I'm not sure of the website, I used Illustrator to edit the file. Hope you got the answer to the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239722/discussion-between-bharats-and-efesahin).

Comment: Okay dude let's go

Comment: can you answer me

Comment: Yeah sure! Please look into the chat

Comment: It's worked. I just make Icon's color white and background transparent

Answer (score 11):

In my case, the issue was that I was placing the

`<meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" … />`

tag under the main `<activity/>` tag in the AndroidManifest.xml

Apparently, it should be under the `<application/>` tag (higher in the hierarchy).

Comment: Holy c&%p that was it. Thank you so much. Wasted a day with this pile.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded this package wich generate launcher icons autuomatically and it works perfectly

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the manifest line to this:

```
<meta-data   android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_ic_launcher" />
```

From your screenshots it appears you only have the ic_stat_ic_launcher files in different resolutions.

If you want to use the mipmap/ic_launcher file, you'll need to add the different size files to the other mipmap folders (in the same way you have the mipmap/launcher_icon.png files), otherwise it probably won't find which file to use

Comment: I tried this solution, but it did not work..

Answer (score 0):

For those who could not understand the notification icon requirements let me break them down.

Let's consider notification icon **facebook** which is white 'f' with blue circle on the background. Now for the notification icon make the 'f' transparent from the icon and generate the notification icon using `asset manager` in android studio. You will notice the blue background is is transparent and 'f' is white now rest is same place the drawable generated folders in there appropriate folders.

```
<meta-data   
   android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
   android:resource="@drawable/app_icon" />

<meta-data   
   android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
   android:resource="@color/facebook_blue_color" />
```

that's it.