# Setting small icon in Notification above lollipop version

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, heads-up-notifications

I have created heads up notification. As like below,

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                .setContentTitle("Message")
                .setContentText("Recieved Successfully")
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                //.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.green))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
   .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);
        manager.notify(m,notification.build());
```

Above code placed inside a class named NotificationService which extends Service.

I can able to set color using below code,

```
setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent))
```

But using that able to set only a unique color.

**My goal is not that.I want to set my icon with its original color as like in Dominos.

Added below code in Android Manifest,

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/notification_icon" />
```

When I am getting push notification I am starting my Service for displaying notification like below,
startService(new Intent(this,NotificationService.class));

But Im getting notification icon with grey color, not in original color.
Also searched a lot sites and stack question. But the answer for the question regarding this problem is the code for placing notification icon in Android Manifest which I mentioned above. Eventhough I followed the answers, couldn't set the notification icon as like dominos.
I didnt able to find where it is going wrong.
Searched most of the stack questions posted. But not able to find suitable answer for my problem.
[image]

Anybody please help me...

Below is the Notification Im getting.

[image]

As you can see my notification icon consist of two text. And those two contains two different color. Thats what I am trying to achieve. But I am getting only grey color. Setting color will set only one unique color for both h and m. I dont want that.

There is no solution for this?? No one achieved this??

Comment: Could you share screen shot of what you are getting output for above code.

Comment: @SrinivasanM I have added my screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

In the new Android SDKs I think all icons are turned into a plain color.

Look into this question that provides some solutions in notification colors in Lollipop.

[Notification bar icon turns white in Android 5 Lollipop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28387602/notification-bar-icon-turns-white-in-android-5-lollipop)

Comment: already seen that but I want to set two different color. In my icon need to set different color for h and m

Comment: @Kousalya did you manage to fix this issue ?

Comment: @SethuramanSrinivasan No. I could not able to achieve multiple color in small icon. So I just used only one color.

Comment: @Kousalya I am also stuck in this issue.

Comment: @user3066829 I couldn't find solution for this issue. Instead I used a single icon with one color.