# Notification Icon not showing with Android 9

Tags: android, android-9.0-pie

I have an issue regarding  the Notification with android 9, Notification icon is not showing with Android 9. I have use below code for show the icon with notification.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notify);
    /* Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_notify);
    notificationBuilder.setLargeIcon(icon);*/
    notificationBuilder.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorWhite));
} else {
    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notify);
}
```

Comment: For 5.0 Lollipop & later, Notification icons must be entirely white. Refer : https://stackoverflow.com/q/30795431/6334037

Comment: Are these notifications that you show for incoming push messages? If so, have you specified a default notification icon in your manifest to be used for messages received while your app is in the background?

Comment: I have use the icon with transparent background.and this is perfectly show up to android oreo @user392117

Comment: I have already use the default icon with manifest file. code is below.@Michael

Comment: @SandeepSharma Have you tried setting both small and large icons?

Answer (score 1):

Finally i have found the solution(With **Android 9**)

**Step 1:** Your image will be white with transparent background.

**Step 2:** You have set the background color according to your app icon.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

           notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_appoint);// this is the white image with transparent background
            notificationBuilder.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGreen));
        } else {
            notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notify); // this is normal image 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Implementation of `Notification Builder` for below and above Lollipop OS version would be:


NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new 
NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon(notificationBuilder));

private int getNotificationIcon(NotificationCompat.Builder 
notificationBuilder) {

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
         int color = 0x008000;
         notificationBuilder.setColor(color);
         return R.drawable.app_icon_lolipop_above;

 } 
 return R.drawable.app_icon_lolipop_below;
 }
```

Comment: kindly check my updated answer if you have any concern let me know