# Not able to change Icon in android studio using setsmallIcon

Tags: java, android, push-notification, android-notifications

Not able to change Icon in android studio using setsmallIcon in NotificationCompat.Builder

below is the code which i am trying and testing it on android 10

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        getFirebaseMessage(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    public void getFirebaseMessage(String title, String msg){

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "myFirebaseChannel")
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(msg)
                .setAutoCancel(true);


        NotificationManagerCompat managerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);

        managerCompat.notify(101, builder.build());
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting a white square icon in the notification?

Comment: @rahat yes...sort of... I am getting a white circle

Comment: You have to use a monochrome png image for the notification icon.

Comment: @rahat can you provide me the link for the sample monochrome png image for the notification icon which i can use

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30795431/android-push-notifications-icon-not-displaying-in-notification-white-square-sh

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the icon size to 16x16 px and use only white colour because notification icons must be entirely white.

Comment: do you have any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You need an icon size of 16x16px and use only white color, but this `NotificationCompat.Builder` that you are using would only help you in Application Live state, not killed state.

Comment: do you have any other suggestion?