# Firebase push notifications show wrong icon when app in background

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I'm using Firebase push notifications in my app that come from a server. When the app is in foreground, the correct notification icon is displayed. But when the app is in background, there's a [filled circle instead](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9S51m.png) of the notification icon.

I have looked at similar issues, and I am using the correct values in my manifest. Here's what I have in my manifest:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
    android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_name" />
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
    android:resource="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

The notification color value seems to be working correctly. The filled circle is that of my app's primary color, and if I change it to some random RGB value, it updates. But the notification icon is always a filled circle no matter what.

And here is how I'm handling my notifications when in foreground, but that works correctly:

```
private fun showNotification(notification: RemoteMessage) {
    createNotificationChannel()

    val notificationId = notification.data["notificationId"]
    val feedItemId = notification.data["itemId"]
    val feedType = notification.data["type"]

    val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java).apply {
        flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
        putExtra(EXTRA_NOTIFICATION, true)
        putExtra(EXTRA_NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationId)
        putExtra(EXTRA_NOTIFICATION_FEED_ITEM_ID, feedItemId)
        putExtra(EXTRA_NOTIFICATION_FEED_TYPE, feedType)
    }

    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, (0..1000).random(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)

    val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, getString(R.string.notification_channel_id))
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name)
        .setContentTitle(notification.notification?.title ?: "")
        .setContentText(notification.notification?.body ?: "")
        .setStyle(NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
            .bigText(notification.notification?.body ?: ""))
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

    with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(this)) {
        notify(System.currentTimeMillis().toInt(), builder.build())
    }
}
```

So the notification icon is not the problem (as suggested in similar questions), as it displays correctly when the app is in foreground.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Push Notifications: Icon not displaying in notification, white square shown instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30795431/android-push-notifications-icon-not-displaying-in-notification-white-square-sh)

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact problem and for me what solved it was adding this to the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_notification" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem and solution after researching for 3 days!

From my experience the issue you have is your meta data for your default_notification_icon and color are probably inside service tag in MainFireBaseMessagingService of AndroidManifest.xml

Copy those two meta data and place it inside application tag too.

Note that the icon supplied must be **white** logo with **transparent background**.

That way in MIUI devices such as redmi and motorola, the plain white/black box notification icon issue won't come up.