# Android : Firebase Notification - small icon not changed, its showing app icon by default

Tags: android, kotlin, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

Firebase notification : App icon shown as notification icon by default  even set other icon as setSmallIcon()

In manifest

```
  <application
    android:name=".ApplicationRoot"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_stat_name"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    tools:ignore="AllowBackup,GoogleAppIndexingWarning"
    tools:replace="android:allowBackup,android:icon"
    tools:targetApi="m">
             ....

 <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_name" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/white" />
```

in coding

```
    var notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name)
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setContentText(messageBody)
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
```

Instead of showing **R.drawable.ic_stat_name** am getting my app logo in the notification.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Push Notifications: Icon not displaying in notification, white square shown instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30795431/android-push-notifications-icon-not-displaying-in-notification-white-square-sh)

Comment: @BroscR already i checked all of the answer nothing worked

Comment: Which firebase version you use implementation and Can you post add FirebaseMessagingService  ?

Comment: it doesn't work for me either, can you contact me if you can find the answer?

Comment: @BroscR com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.3.1