# Android 12 - Push notification icon problem (Firebase messaging)

Tags: android, reactjs, push-notification

I have an app for android built with Reactjs + Capacitor. The implementation follows the installation guide on the Firebase documentation and I am not using a custom notification layout.
By using the following code in the manifest I am able to receive notifications with icons properly on any device that doesn't use Android 12

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" />
```

But on Android 12 the icon is not visible. I tried several different ways to include the icon, with either a direct png or xml resource.

What exactly am I missing for Android 12 devices specifically? Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30795431/android-push-notifications-icon-not-displaying-in-notification-white-square-sh

Comment: Yes, I saw that post but it doesn't seem to apply in my case. There it's a 6 year old problem while in my case seems to work on anything except the newest android.

Comment: Any help did you got? Even I didn't get any icon picture in android 12

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your Meta-data is under the `application` tag and not the activity tag. At least this was the issue in my case, notification icon seemed to work fine except on Android 12. Putting the meta-data under application tag fixed it for me.

Comment: This was my issue. I had the meta-data tag under the `application` and within the `provider` tag. It needs to be at the root `application`