# Android notification small icon background color is not working properly

Tags: android, notifications, icons, android-notifications

this is the code snippet I am using to show notification small icon and to set background color

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID);
        builder.setSmallIcon(getSmallIcon());
        builder.setColor(getColor(R.color.new_theme_color));
builder.setContentTitle(getTitle());
        builder.setContentText(WebUtils.fromHtml(body));
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
        builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle());
```

this is working as expected on some devices[expected image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BzQY.png)
but on some devices the small icon looks like this [not expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ovup.png)
what I need to do to set background properly on all devices.

if I use the app icon directly that is also not working, found the solution to that problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30795431/android-push-notifications-icon-not-displaying-in-notification-white-square-sh) after changing the image to greyscale image it's working fine, but on some devices color is setting to image instead of background.

Answer (score 0):

I think your image is not transparent, you can use https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html to convert the notification icons, maybe some cases cannot convert because of colourful or detailed images.
Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you for the reply, but I am using transparent image only https://svgshare.com/s/vYg here is the link to that vector image, on some devices color is applying to icon instead of background.