# Android Notification Large Icon Spec?

Tags: android, notifications, icons

Where can I find the right dimensions for the Large Icon for Android Notifications?

What do I want? I want a nice looking circle (some color) as a Large icon with a little envelop in it. And add a small icon with its own specs.

The small icon works all fine. But I have a question about the large icon. I searched for some hours now and couldn't find it!

What space can I use for Large Icon? How big is the space? And are there any specs about how big the little envelop in the Large icon should be?

Android Kitkat and above:

Large Icon (space I can fill):   ?
Large Icon (how big must the little envelop be? any specs?):   ?

Below Android KitKat:

I know that below Android KitKat the notifications are a bit different. But what are the specs here?

Large Icon (space I can fill):   ?
Large Icon (how big must the little envelop be? any specs?):   ?

[Large notification icon background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26973820/large-notification-icon-background)
The question is kinda the same as in this question. But this question didn't received a final answer. The accepted answer didn't convinced me because there was a discussion in the comments without a conclusion.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220738/honeycomb-notifications-how-to-set-largeicon-to-the-right-size

Comment: They are scaling the bitmap, This means that if i create a small (to small) icon, it will be stretched out and get blurry

Answer (score 4):

Large Icon must be 256x256 px for xxxhdpi

From OneSignal Documentation for [Android notification icons](https://documentation.onesignal.com/v3.0/docs/customize-notification-icons)

Comment: it is 64 dp, FYI